# Send curl from python

Tags: python, curl, subprocess

I have the following config file in json format:

```
{"end_point":"http://domain.com","auth_token":"e91a0ffe758c194f2326eb4daed0","widgets":{"host_info":"fd8a63a33d1d15521e3499289a312","memory_info":"0bc2c3345ba7b129f3328bc4c507ad","cpu_info":"5a2b41cd21d56773250dc41dbd73681"}}
```

I am trying to send the data using subprocess.  The question is how to get the data from json file:

```
#Send using subprocess
import subprocess
subprocess.call([
'curl',
'-X',
'POST',
'-H',
'Content-Type: application/json',
'-d',
'{ "auth_token": "GETFROMCONFIGFILE(authtoken)", "widget": "GETFROMCONFIGFILE(widgets)", "title": "Something", "items":[{"label": "TEST", "value": "11"}, {"label": "1", "value": "11"}] }',
'GETFROMFILE(endpoint)'
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

To decode the object, if f is a file object which has been opened for reading:

```
x = json.load(f)
```

And you use dict as usual

```
x["authtoken"]
```

Comment: This is not the answer. I am asking to send data using subprocess and python.

Comment: You are using subprocess, so you can use command line options. Maybe you were asking for pycurl, but there is not pycurl in your question.

Comment: Ok, I changed my answer, open the file, json.load, and then you use x["authtoken"], and so on. First time I read that you wanted to put the whole config file into curl request.